# such [dogecoin]. much burninate. wow!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I came across the little-used [dogecoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dogecoin), 8 followers, 20 questions, and [only one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21488654/1270789) looks somewhat relevant. So with no further ado:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   The questions are more about APIs or apps that use Dogecoin, not about Dogecoin itself.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   There's over 1,000 cryptocoins and at least four have specific sub-sites here, but are the other 996+ on-topic here? I don't really know.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   As I said in the intro, just one looked definitely about coding Dogecoin; the rest were not.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   There is only one Dogecoin, so yes.

There is also the related question of if tags for other coins like [bitcoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bitcoin) and [ethereum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethereum) are also on-topic; if we send the doge to the farm, do we similarly get rid of (or migrate?) the other coins?

[image]

Thanks to Zoe for the picture!

Comment: very upvote. useful.

Comment: such pun, much great. (God I hate that meme language...) But the request seems legit, so give Trogdor the mighty burninator a call

Comment: I normally would totally ignore such a trivial tag, but I'm in a Friday mood.

Comment: Not sure if I should downvote for the blatant abuse of the English language, or upvote for the removal of the tag...

Comment: That _one somewhat relevant_ question is about compiling a program from the downloaded source. Not really programming-related imho, might be SuperUser. Since this tag has <50 questions, it might qualify for a quick burninate if a trusted (>20K) user feels like condoning it and is knowledgeable on the topic.

Comment: WOW
PLZ NO REMOVE
MUCH SAD
REMOV TOMORO

Comment: But we're not at the moon yet! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=000al7ru3ms

Comment: That last part is [much better with an image](https://i.imgur.com/SUnj4Hp.png)

Comment: ...Who voted to close this as opinion based? All burninate requests are subjective.

Comment: @jpmc26 if we close and reopen it, we can find out ;)

Comment: The image is wrong though, doge is supposed to use colored Comic Sans

Comment: WOW TAG DEAD SAD TODAY

Answer (score 6):

After reading this post, especially the part:

> The questions are more about APIs or apps that use Dogecoin, not about Dogecoin itself.

I checked all the posts in [dogecoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dogecoin). Most of them refer to the dogecoin API and not dogecoin itself. Therefore one possible outcome would be to rename it to [dogecoin-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dogecoin-api).

The ones which are about apps that use dogecoin are not even on topic for Stack Overflow, therefore, we can close them.

Answer (score 1):

I do think "crypto currency" is such a hot topic right now that questions about integrating those into websites/whatever can't be considered off topic; similar thing could be said about (say) `google-maps` integration.

Now one could say that dogecoin is just too limited (given only 4 questions). And thus should be "axed". But I'd like to see something such as "cryptocurrency" coming into its place.

Comment: I would've thought such a tag already exists, but at the time of writing, it appears not: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/788569/currency-tags.

Comment: Does *"not enough questions about <subject>"* really make it off topic? That sounds like a very poor criterion to decide if a question should be on/off topic here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Well not the question, but the tag itself becomes unnecessary if hardly anyone uses it, especially in lieu of a more general tag. (As I suggest in this post)